# Уменьшить расстояние до края. Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, margin, padding

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как уменьшить расстояние между краями графика и краями окна?

Можно ли контролировать каждую сторону отдельно?

[image: Как уменьшить расстояние до края?]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
arr = []
for i in range(0, 16):
    arr.append(i)
    
fig = mpl.figure(figsize=(16,9))
    
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelsize = 8.5)
ax.barh(arr, arr)
    
mpl.show()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: код добавил, надеюсь, это поможет найти ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

arr = []

for i in range(0, 16):
    arr.append(i)
   
margins = {                                               # +++                                          
    "left"   : 0.040,
    "bottom" : 0.060,
    "right"  : 0.990,
    "top"    : 0.990   
}

   
fig = mpl.figure(figsize=(16,9))

fig.subplots_adjust(**margins)                            # +++
    
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelsize = 8.5)
ax.barh(arr, arr)
    
mpl.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы волшебник!) Спасибо большое! 
Не сочтите за труд, подскажите, пожалуйста,
а) в каких единицах измерения происходит магия?
б) где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: @PaulManik   https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html . Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Возможно также вот так (цифры разумеется приведены просто для демонстрации возможностей и их надо подбирать в конкретном случае):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.left'] = 0.01
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.bottom'] = 0.1
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.right'] = 0.5
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.top'] =0.5
```